# Unity ReplayKit how to bypass native preview?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, replaykit

Using the Unity ReplayKit API from https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/Apple.ReplayKit.ReplayKit.html
I can record, preview and share screen recordings just fine, however due to design & UX requirements I need to have custom buttons to invoke sharing/saving of the recorded clip. I need to show the recorded clip right after the capture (for example like videotexture on a plane) in the background with custom share button overlays.

Is there a way to access the clip captured by ReplayKit and bypass iOS native preview screen?

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 11, you can have direct access to the video. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/606/

You can save it using AVAssetWriter, then do whatever you want with it after that.

This project doesn't completely work, but will head you in the right direction: https://medium.com/@giridharvc7/replaykit-screen-recording-8ee9a61dd762